# Replace environment variables in Spring properties file other than application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Spring Boot will automatically resolve any `${ENV}` placeholders in `application.properties` files, with the respective environment variable.

However such resolution will not happen when I provide a `quartz.properties` through a `PropertiesFactoryBean` file for Quartz configuration.

```
@Bean
public Properties getQuartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Is there any Spring way of replacing these environment variables in the property file without utilising an external library?

Comment: you can use annotation @PropertySource to mention diff. properties files based on environment, it is called as spring profiling. please go through spring profiling.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a new class to provide the properties (annotated with @Configuration) and also mention the @PropertySource

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:quartz.properties")
public class QuartzConfig {
      //...
}
```

In this way your spring boot application can read as many properties file as you want.

Comment: Is there a way to get access to that properties file as a `Properties` object? The only way I can pass that config to Quartz is via the [initialize](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html#initialize(java.util.Properties)) method, and that accepts only a `Properties` object